# Заставить показывать монитор

Tags: linux

Как заставить линукс подавать сигнал на D-sub выход, несмотря на то, что монитора нет?

(Фактически есть очки, которые не определяются как монитор, но изображение показывают как он. Например, в биосе можно увидеть изображение, потому что в нём компьютер не заморачивается о том, есть ли монитор, а просто подаёт сигналы на все выходы)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю такие вещи вроде в xorg.conf должны задаваться статически .. хотя может уже и ошибаюсь - тыщу лет не ковырял десктопный линух, все сервера как-то )

должно быть что-то подобное, типа "не определять подключенные мониторы, форсировать присутствие"

```
Option           "UseDisplayDevice" "DFP"
Option           "UseEDID" "FALSE"
Option           "ModeValidation" "NoEdidModes"
```